# C# ASP.NET Core Web API DLL was imported using LibraryImport, but it doesn't find a binary file that exists in the same folder during debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building a server using ASP.NET Core Web API.
As part of the logic, I am using an external DLL written in C++ and loading it using `LibraryImport`.
To perform its operation, the DLL expects a binary file that is located together with the DLL in the same directory.

Here is something strange happening: when I debug the code in an ASP.NET Core Web API project, the DLL fails to find the required binary file. However, when I transferred the exact logic to projects like Console, Windows Form, or WPF, the DLL successfully finds the binary file, even though I made sure that the binary file and the dll are in the output directory as required in all cases.

Additionally, when I run the executable file directly from the output directory of the ASP.NET Core Web API project without Visual Studio, everything works as expected.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how can it be fixed?
Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions; I'm presenting the issue with all the information I have. The logic that the library performs is minimal, and when I try to call a method from the DLL, I encounter a descriptive error indicating that the binary file cannot be found. @Blindy

Comment: I'm sure you do, but there's no descriptive error relayed in your question to help us debug your problem. And I can only assume you don't even realize the assumptions you're making are probably false, for example assuming that ASP.NET binaries are ran from the same folder that you compile in (where you presumably checked the existence of your DLL -- you never checked it from the actual binary folder did you?).

Comment: This is not an assumption, and I'm not presuming anything. I am documenting the behavior occurring in my code in the hope that someone who recognizes this behavior from their own experience can share insights and tell me why it is happening and how to disable it. @Blindy

Comment: DLL file exists in Debug folder? Pls, try add folder with imported dll to path system variable.

Comment: I tried, it didn't help. I think it's something specific to the way ASP.NET works because it does work in other types of projects. @MihalBy